# Download mail from your Gmail attachments without user intervention

Tags: android, download, gmail

I have read and there are many examples of this, about which you can send an email with their attachments without user intervention, but I have not read about the possibility to download attachments from a Gmail account programmatically without user intervention. I mean the Android operating system. Any link or example or guidance would be appreciated. Greetings.

Comment: You should be able to use either the POP or the IMAP protocols. You should do a google search on Android and one of those protocols, you'll probably find something.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [script to do just this](https://github.com/drewgbarnes/GmailBackup). It uses python and the IMAP library to download all emails on a GMail account, including attachments if you want.

Although you said for android...the GMail account should be independent of the phone itself so as long as you can login to the GMail account you should be able to programmatically get the attachments as I did with this script.